# SimpleCursorAdapter queries

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

I have a process to create the content for a view that I'd like to defer until the view for that cursor row is visible.  Processing the file with the initial filtered query could be problematic if there are far more results than visible.

When a SimpleCursorAdapter has a cursor with many rows and it wants to generate a view does it query that individual row or would this logic have to be in openFile()?

Answer (score 0):

Need to be with individual row, try to getItemId.
And you will return row by row with id on listView or Adapter.

Comment: Cant really follow your response.